# Solving $\sqrt{\frac{D_1}{\sin(2\theta_1+2t)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_2}{\sin(2\theta_2+2t)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_3}{\sin(2\theta_3+2t)}}$ for $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> I have this equation
> $$
> \sqrt{\frac{D_1}{\sin\left(2\theta_1+2\Delta\theta\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_2}{\sin\left(2\theta_2+2\Delta\theta\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_3}{\sin\left(2\theta_3+2\Delta\theta\right)}}
> $$
> where I have to solve for $\Delta\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

What I've tried so far is this:

[image: my attempt]

Right now this is all I have and I'm stuck and I don't know if I'm even going in a right direction.

Comment: Where are the $10$ coming from ? Is $\Delta \theta$ supposed to be small ?

Comment: 10 does not matter here i guess. Delta theta is 0 ≤ Δθ ≤ π

Comment: I have improved my answer : there is now an explicit solution. Btw: what is the origin of your problem ? Is it coming from an application in some domain of Physics ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, it is coming from dynamics

Answer (score 2):

Triggered by the answer of Blue, I have completely changed my answer.

The master word of this question is "compatibility" of the parameters $D_1,D_2,D_3,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ between themselves to ensure a solution is possible.

Let us write the equations under the slightly simplified way :

$$\frac{D_1}{\sin(a+x)}=\frac{D_2}{\sin(b+x)}=\frac{D_3}{\sin(c+x)} \tag{1}$$

(1) is equivalent to the proportionality of the following 3D vectors:

$$\vec{OM_x}:=\begin{pmatrix}\sin(a+x)\\ \sin(b+x) \\ \sin(c+x)\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ \vec{OD}:=\begin{pmatrix}D_1 \\ D_2 \\ D_3 \end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

[image]

But $\vec{OM_x}$ describe a planar curve because of the expansion:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\sin(a+x)\\ \sin(b+x) \\ \sin(c+x)\end{pmatrix}=\cos(x)\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\sin(a)\\ \sin(b) \\ \sin(c)\end{pmatrix}}_{V_1}+\sin(x)\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(a)\\ \cos(b) \\ \cos(c)\end{pmatrix}}_{V_2}\tag{2}$$

which is in fact a 3D ellipse (intersection of a plane and a cylinder). Therefore :

- **in general, there are no solutions.**
- there is a (unique) solution if and only if vector $\vec{OD}$ belongs to the plane of this ellipse.

Otherwise said, if and only if $\vec{OD}$ is orthogonal to the normal vector to the plane containing the ellipse which is compatibility condition:

$$\begin{pmatrix}D_1 \\ D_2 \\ D_3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\sin(b-c)\\ \sin(c-a) \\ \sin(a-b)\end{pmatrix}}_{V_1 \times V_2}=0\tag{3}$$

(where the point means dot product).

Said again: There is a unique solution iff (3) is fulfilled.

How can we find the solution explicitly ?

I am going to give an answer necessitating the linear algebra concept of kernel: indeed, if $\vec{OD}$ belongs to the plane determined by $V_1$ and $V_2$, we can find
$k_1$ and $k_2$ such that:

$$\vec{OD}=k_1V_1+k_2V_2\tag{4}$$

Otherwise said,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
D_1&\sin a&\cos a\\ 
D_2&\sin b&\cos b\\ 
D_3&\sin c&\cos c 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\k_1\\k_2 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0 
\end{pmatrix}\tag{5}$$

for certain $k_1$ and $k_2$ that we can explicitate:

Let us for example assume that $S:=\sin(c-b) \ne 0$.

Then an explicit solution of (5) is

$$\begin{cases}k_1&=&\frac{1}{S}(D_3 \cos b-D_2 \cos c)\\
k_2&=&\frac{1}{S}(D_2 \sin c-D_3 \sin b)\end{cases}
\tag{6}$$

Last step: from the comparison of (2) and (4) (under a normalization constraint), $x$ is solution of the system:

$$\begin{cases}\cos x&=&\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}\\
\sin x&=&\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}\end{cases}
\tag{7}$$

**Numerical application :** Let us take:

$$D_1=D_2=D_3=1, \ \ a=b=\frac{\pi}{3}, \ \ c=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

(verifying compatibility condition (3)) ; formulas (6) and (7) give:

$$\sin x = \cos x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \implies \ x=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Verification of (1): indeed, we have

$$\frac{1}{\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3}+\tfrac{\pi}{4})}=\frac{1}{\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3}+\tfrac{\pi}{4})}=\frac{1}{\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{6}+\tfrac{\pi}{4})} $$

Comment: Hi  Jean-Marie ! You always impresse me with your skills in geometry. Cheers and $+1$ for sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Hi Claude ! Thanks for the compliment... Here we are blocked by an exceptional April snowfall : over 30 cm in St Etienne... Global warming they say...

Comment: OK for your answer. Now, **I** say that this is not for a triangle. Then what ?

Comment: > triangle with lengthsides $D_1,D_2,D_3$. This is not the case, as it was never stated this way.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici You are right to ask the question of **equivalence** of this issue with the geometrical interpretation. I am going to modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Upon squaring and expanding the sines, we have an equality of three expressions of the form
$$
 \frac{D_i}{\sin2\theta_i\cos2\Delta\theta+\cos2\theta_i\sin2\Delta\theta} \tag1$$
We can therefore write
$$\frac{c_1}{t_1+\tan2\Delta\theta}
=\frac{c_2}{t_2+\tan2\Delta\theta}
=\frac{c_3}{t_3+\tan2\Delta\theta} \tag2$$
where $c_i := D_i\sec2\theta_i$ and $t_i:=\tan2\theta_i$.

Solving the first equality gives
$$\tan2\Delta\theta= \frac{t_1c_2 - t_2c_1}{c_1 - c_2}\tag3$$
which OP can solve for $\Delta\theta$ in the desired range. $\square$

**Note.** Solving the second equality in $(2)$ gives an alternate form of $(3)$; the fact that these (and a third form, from equating the first and last expressions) must match imposes the following condition on the constants:
$$c_1(t_2-t_3)+c_2(t_3-t_1)+c_3(t_1-t_2) = 0 \tag4$$
Back-substituting to trigonometric form gives
$$D_1 \sin2(\theta_2-\theta_3)+D_2\sin2(\theta_3-\theta_1)+D_3\sin2(\theta_1-\theta_2) = 0 \tag5$$
which matches condition $(3)$ in [@JeanMarie's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419163/409).

Comment: We are both on a compatibility condition between parameters (see my "remasterized" answer abandoning the triangle answer which was a deadend) under different forms...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Indeed, I should have taken the extra step and back-substituted my condition (4) into trigonometric form. My new edit does that, showing that our answers are compatible in that regard. ... In any case, I like your vectorized formulation.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that this is not related to a triangle Using algebra, with $x=2\Delta\theta$

$$\sqrt{\frac{D_1}{\sin\left(2\theta_1+x\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_2}{\sin\left(2\theta_2+x\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{D_3}{\sin\left(2\theta_3+x\right)}}$$ So, consider that you need to minimize
$$\Phi(x)=\Bigg[\sqrt{\frac{\sin (2 \theta_1+x)}{D_1}}-\sqrt{\frac{\sin (2 \theta_2+x)}{D_2}}\Bigg]^2+\Bigg[\sqrt{\frac{\sin (2 \theta_2+x)}{D_2}}-\sqrt{\frac{\sin (2 \theta_3+x)}{D_3}}\Bigg]^2$$ with respect to $x$. This means that you want $\Phi'(x)=0$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac \pi 2$. This is not a big deal (just solving  $\Phi'(x)=0$)  but I do not see any explicit solution but numerically the problem is quite simple; the only unpleasant point is the expression of $\Phi''(x)$ you need if you use Newton method.

A major issue is that a solution could not exist. Graphing first could be a good idea.

Comment: In fact, Claude, I must say  "thank you" : your question asking about the alleged necessity of having a triangle interpretation has generated a very different (explicit) solution (I have abandoned this triangular interpretation).